# Matching field by omitting spaces - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to find the mongo document by matching the "Tel" field value,

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f047aa5b9e5c7c13000000"),    
    "data" : [
        {
            "Id" : "1", 
            "Country" : "India", 
            "Timezone" : "Europe/Paris", 
            **"Tel" : "03 20 14 97 70",** 
            "Prenom" : "ddd", 
            "Email" : "ddd@gmail.com", 
            "City" : "Chennai", 
            "date" : "", 
            "active" : "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

how to fetch the above document from mongo collection using the below find method without space in "Tel" field,

```
>db.test.find({"data.Tel":"0320149770"})
```

Please can anyone help me !!!

Comment: I´m sorry but that does not seem to be possible. Someone might be able to out prove me though.

Comment: is not possible to apply any reg exp to keys ?

Comment: If you have saved the "tel" entry like that for good visual when presenting the data to the viewer, please consider saving the "tel" as "0320149770" instead and separate  the numbers upon presentation.
This also minimizes the weight of the saved document a little.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is what you really want to do on a regular basis then you are best off adding another field to the document that has the string present without any spaces.

The reason why is though there are functions you can perform to do the search, none of the methods are able to use an index to match the document, so this means scanning everything in the collection in order to find a match.

You can do this with JavaScript evaluation in a [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) clause:

```js
db.test.find(function() { 
    return this.data.some(function(el) {
        el.Tel.replace(/ /g,"") == "0320149770"
    });
});
```

But don't do that because it's really bad. you are better off just updating all the data instead:

```js
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.data = doc.data.map(function(el) {
        el.TelNum = el.Tel.replace(/ /g,"");
    })
    db.test.update({ "_id": doc._id },{ "$set": { "data": doc.data } });
})
```

Or something along those lines to have a field without spaces all ready to search on directly.